# Which of the following two implementation of string permutation algorithm is better in terms of time and space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, permutation, space-complexity

> Problem Statement: Given a string, write a program which finds all the permutations of the string.

I have implemented it in two different ways, and according to my (possibly erroneous) time complexity analysis the second one does lesser computations, yet in real-time performance, the first one outperforms the second one.

Questions:

1. Is my time analysis correct? Why does the computational performance differ?
2. Which of the implementations would be better in terms of space requirements?
3. In the recursive calls, I am returning immutable datatypes instead of using an mutable accumulator (I read somewhere that this is good practice). Is this advisable, or could better performance be achieved (in space or time) by using a mutable variable or static variable?
4. Instead of returning List, or would it better to wrap things up as a  Iterator? I read somewhere that might be better as so that you don't need to keep all permutations in memory at once, and don't need to pre-calculate all permutations before you start doing anything with any of them. How would the code look then?
5. Could I optimize it further by using StringBuffer or StringBuilder instead of Strings? I think the compiler automatically implements the concatenations in  using StringBuilder, so is this fine?
6. Any other suggestions to improve the code?

### The first version:

```java
    private static List<String> permuteOne (String partial, String rest) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (rest.length() == 1) {
            result.add(partial + rest); 
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < rest.length(); j++) {;
                result.addAll(permuteOne(partial + rest.charAt(j), rest.substring(0,j) + rest.substring(j+1)));
            }
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(result);
    }
```

> Time complexity T(n) = n * T(n-1)
>
> > numOperations(firstVersion) = n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ...n!
>
> Space complexity: ??

### The Second Version:

```java
    private static List<String> permuteTwo (String remaining) {  
        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (remaining.length() == 1) {
             newList.add(remaining);
        } else {        
            List<String> partialPerms = permuteTwo(remaining.substring(0, remaining.length()-1)); 
            for(String permutation: partialPerms )
                for(int j = 0; j <= permutation.length(); j++){
                    newList.add(permutation.substring(0, j) + remaining.charAt(remaining.length()-1) + permutation.substring(j));
            }   
        }
        return newList;
    }
```

> Time complexity T(n) = n! + T(n-1)
>
> > numOperations(secondVersion) =  1! + 2! + 3! + ...n! < n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ...n!  = numOperations(firstVersion)
>
> Space Complexity: n*n!? <- Not sure of this

Comment: What is the algorithm supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry! Just added the details.

Comment: I don’t see how you come to the conclusion that “the second one does lesser computations”. The time complexity of a nested loop has to be the product of the number of outer iterations and the number of inner iterations.

Comment: Isn't it clear how I arrived at it from the recursion equation mentioned?
While the time complexity of a nested loop has to be the product of the number of outer iterations and the number of inner iterations, these numbers differ for the two implementations (according to my reading of the recursion tree).  If you run it using a count variable before each atomic operation, you'd see it for yourself.

Comment: What are you calling an “atomic operation” here?

Comment: String concatenation